# update nested object from nested flatlist and limit amount of checkbox checked

Tags: react-native

I run a fetch from a server that returns an object that you can see an exemple of here:

```
{
    "info": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "name": "name sample",
            "description": "description sample",
            "img": "0",
            "price": "14.00",
            "Omega": "0",
            "categories": []
        }
    ],
    "categories": [
        {
            "ID": "1",
            "name": "base",
            "min": "1",
            "max": "1",
            "actual": "2",
            "options": [
                {
                    "ID": "1",
                    "name": "peanuts",
                    "supplement": "1",
                    "checked": "true"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "2",
                    "name": "cheesecake",
                    "supplement": "0",
                    "checked": "false"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "9",
                    "name": "carrots",
                    "supplement": "3",
                    "checked": "true"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "2",
            "name": "enhancer",
            "min": "1",
            "max": "1",
            "actual": "0",
            "options": [
                {
                    "ID": "3",
                    "name": "mojito",
                    "supplement": "3",
                    "checked": "false"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "3",
            "name": "berry",
            "min": "1",
            "max": "3",
            "actual": "1",
            "options": [
                {
                    "ID": "10",
                    "name": "banana",
                    "supplement": "0",
                    "checked": "true"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "11",
                    "name": "blueberry",
                    "supplement": "2",
                    "checked": "false"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "4",
            "name": "special",
            "min": "1",
            "max": "4",
            "actual": "0",
            "options": [
                {
                    "ID": "12",
                    "name": "moon",
                    "supplement": "1",
                    "checked": "false"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "8",
            "name": "ultima",
            "min": "0",
            "max": "1",
            "actual": "1",
            "options": [
                {
                    "ID": "13",
                    "name": "ultimo",
                    "supplement": "5",
                    "checked": "true"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and then to parse all this result into a list of checkboxes i use this code:

```
         <FlatList
           data={data.categories}
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name + item.ID}
           // style={{marginBottom: 200}}
           renderItem={({ item }) => (
             <View
               style={{
                 marginTop: 0,
                 marginLeft: 0,
                 marginRight: 0,
                 marginBottom: 0,
                 flexDirection: "column",
               }}
             >
               <View
                 style={{
                   paddingTop: 10,
                   paddingBottom: 0,
                   flexDirection: "column",
                 }}
               >
                 <View
                   style={{
                     paddingTop: 10,
                     paddingBottom: 10,
                     flexDirection: "column",
                     borderTopColor: "lightgrey",
                     borderTopWidth: 1,
                     borderBottomColor: "lightgrey",
                     borderBottomWidth: 1,
                     marginTop: 10,
                   }}
                 >
                   <Text
                     style={{
                       fontSize: 18,
                       color: "black",
                       textAlign: "left",
                       paddingHorizontal: 10,
                       fontWeight: "bold",
                     }}
                   >
                     {item.name}
                   </Text>
                   <View
                     style={{
                       flexDirection: "row",
                     }}
                   >
                     {item.min > "0" ? (
                       <Text
                         style={{
                           fontSize: 12,
                           color: "red",
                           textAlign: "left",
                           paddingLeft: 10,
                         }}
                       >
                         Requis
                       </Text>
                     ) : (
                       <Text></Text>
                     )}
                     <Text
                       style={{
                         fontSize: 12,
                         color: "black",
                         textAlign: "left",
                         paddingHorizontal: 5,
                       }}
                     >
                       Choose between {item.min} and {item.max} options
                     </Text>
                   </View>
                 </View>

                 <FlatList
                   data={item.options}
                   style={{}}
                   keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name + item.ID}
                   renderItem={({ item: innerData, index }) => (
                     

                     <View>
                       <View style={styles.optionView}>
                         
                         <CheckBox
                           containerStyle={{ marginLeft: 0, width: "100%" }}
                           title={
                             innerData.supplement > "0" ? (
                               <View
                                 style={{
                                   flexDirection: "row",
                                   justifyContent: "space-between",
                                   paddingHorizontal: 5,
                                 }}
                               >
                                 <Text style={styles.optionDescription}>{innerData.name}</Text>
                                 <Text  style={styles.optionPrice}>+ {innerData.supplement}</Text>
                               </View>
                               
                             ) : (
                               <View
                                 style={{
                                   flexDirection: "row",
                                   justifyContent: "space-between",
                                   paddingHorizontal: 5,
                                 }}
                               >
                               <Text style={styles.optionDescription}>
                                 {innerData.name}
                               </Text></View>
                             )
                           }
                           textStyle={{ color: "black" }}
                           checkedIcon="check-square-o"
                           uncheckedIcon="square-o"
                           checked= {stringToBoolean(innerData.checked)}
                           checkedColor="green"
                           uncheckedColor="green"
                           onPress={() => {
                             stringToBoolean(innerData.checked) == false ? setData({ ...data, innerData.checked: true }) : setData({ ...data, innerData.checked: false });
                             
                             
                           
                           
                           
                           }}
                         />
                       </View>
                     </View>
                   )}
                 />
               </View>
             </View>
           )}
         />
```

As you can see some chekboxes come prechecked from the source, some not, my idea was to update the original json object everytime a checkbox gets updated to keep track and thus disable or enable a checkbox according to actual value and the min/max values, but for the life of me i can't seem to get the code to update the object right:

```
onPress={() => {stringToBoolean(innerData.checked) == false ? setData({ ...data, innerData.checked: true }) : setData({ ...data, innerData.checked: false });}
```

Any idea how to solve that? and is my idea sound for the whole process of limiting checkboxes?

I started learning react-native and javascript late November and i'm having a blast, big thank you to all the community here sharing ideas and solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you "Great" for your answer, i have meanwhile figured out the answer, i'll share it here for others:

the solution is as follow:

```
                        onPress={() => {stringToBoolean(innerData.checked) == false
                            ? Number(item.actual) < item.max
                              ? ((innerData.checked = "true"),
                                (item.actual = Number(item.actual) + 1))
                              : showToast("max options reached!")
                            : (innerData.checked = "false",
                              item.actual = Number(item.actual) - 1);
                        }}
```

Cheers folks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using a key prop in the checkbox component